# When should I use a form in html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

With Ajax and dynamic pages seeming to take over the Internet when should one use an HTML form? I can think of a few places(login pages, or really any static page that doesn't change dynamically)

What really has come to mind is things like knockout where you have a model that can control the HTML on the page. You would t really have to do a form submit since you have the model in json and you can just do an Ajax call to send the data to the server.

I always figured forms added extra protection than just doing an ajax request, although I understand that you should never ever trust user input.

Comment: But why would you want to do a form submit in the 2nd example, and then an Ajax request? ... I don't think this is a question that can be answered well, if you have an Ajax only app then in theory you don't need forms at all any more, except for forms that submit to an external web site.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but AJAX still needs/utilizes HTML forms and form elements. Also, it's nice to have fallback for users with JS disabled and/or older browsers where the JS could break and you'd still like the form to be accessible.

Comment: @ravb79 It needs input elements, but it doesn't need the `<form>` container.

Comment: Could you upload images without a form? (I really wouldn't know)

Comment: Even if you're using AJAX, lots of plugins are designed to work with forms. For instance, jquery-validate validates all the input elements of a form, and jQuery Form Plugin submits a form via AJAX.

Comment: Which brings up another issue: why load all those extra js sources when you have an element in place that can handle it all for you?

Comment: A form is a form, no matter how it is submitted, you're still filling out a **form**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms are used, basically, for user input. Why use `<form>` over just `GetElementById` when passing through AJAX? I was facing a similar question just today, and I concluded the answer was so I could use this piece of code:

```
$("#YOUR_FORM").submit( function () {    
    serialized = $(this).serializeArray(); // <-- this saves time
```

Other than that, is `<form>` needed in a modern jQuery-based application? Not as far as I can see, but maybe someone more experienced than me will know why. Also I suppose it adds some organization...

If you're unfamiliar with that function, it will do the work of collecting your form data and putting it into the `$_POST` array for you, for whatever serverside file you're POSTing to.

Answer (score 0):

I still use form on most of my apps, I just use AJAX/JavaScript to intercept the form.submit() to validate my inputs.

Here are other reason, why to still use form:

1. whenever the user press ENTER on a text input, it submits the form, so no need to handle the keypress=13 then.
2. You can also use "required" attributes on input tags and let the browser handle the validations.

Note that in case your JavaScript fails, if there are errors or your CDN fails to load,
your apps should still be able to survive if you use normal forms.

Answer (score -1):

For example, if you want to support file upload and also want to avoid 3rd party plugins such as `applets`, `Flash` and `Silverlight`.

Basically, `AJAX` does not support `multipart` data. I have seen forms with file fields that target `<iframe>` to simulate AJAX "look and feel" but it is only possible to do so much.